# Minecraft Not Teleporting Me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I type in `/tp Sentinel Gaming -419 43 356` and press enter the bar goes blank and doesn't teleport me. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it.
On a side note, every time I try to give myself a Command Block it says `That player cannot be found` so how can I fix that as well.
Thank You in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Registered usernames can not include spaces. As commands in Minecraft use space as a separator for arguments, they will take "Sentinel" as the name for the player to search for, and then "Gaming" as the second argument (such as x-coordinate or item) and budge everything over. This will cause an error.

If you are on a server or using some kind of plugin/mod that allows you to change your name, you should type your actual account name rather than your set nickname.

If you are using a cracked/pirated version of Minecraft, stop.

If your name contains an underscore ( _ ), make sure you are typing that rather than a space.

As an alternative to typing your name, you could use @p. For example:

```
/tp @p -419 43 356
```

This will target the closest player (which will be the person executing it), and is also shorter than typing/tabbing out your name.

Comment: Ok thanks and no I am on 1.8 it is just the error as I stated above, but Thanks for the help much love bruh

Comment: u can also put it in quotes if u wanna use a space

Answer (score 0):

Usernames can't have spaces, that is why you can't do it. Minecraft sees "Gaming" as the location, so it errors. I recommend you to buy minecraft, or change your username. If you don't want that to happen, you have some problems. I think you need a command block to teleport the nearest player to a location (`tp @p -419 43 359`), however, to get a command block, you need to use cheats (`give player command_block` in 1.7/1.8 or `give player 137` on 1.6 or earlier). The only problem is that you can't give it to you because your name has spaces. So, the best way to do this in my opinion is just changing your username. You can also use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block` in 1.7/1.8 to set a command block in your position, then pick it up and set the command to the teleport nearest player command.

Comment: Ok thanks for the assistance I have already solves the problem with the aforementioned advice.  Thanks tho